swift testing ObservableObject and waiting for async operation before assertions
I am trying to test an observable object. This will make a network request which I have mocked out with dependency injection. The problem I am facing is even though i am awaiting my async function to finish, my assertion in my unit test triggers before setting my published properties. I am for sure missing something but just want any advice to clean up my view model or my tests.
The flow of my vm is as follows. call my fetchWhatsNew function. parse out the data and verify we have a true for show marketing, and a valid url. if so, check a published boolean(shouldShowMarketingPage) true. Then in my swiftUI views I will call the fetch function and display the url if needed.
// View model
final class MarketingViewModel: ObservableObject {

    /// Decides if we need to show the marketing page to the user
    @Published private(set) var shouldShowMarketingPage: Bool = false
    @Published private(set) var whatNewUrl: String?

    /// bool value from the api response
    private var showMarketingFromApi = false
    private(set) var error: Error?

    private let networkingManager: NetworkingManagerImplementation
    private let marketingRowId: String = "i-3JdpsB-rxH"

    init(netwokringManager: NetworkingManagerImplementation = NetworkingManger.shared) {
        self.networkingManager = netwokringManager
    }

    func fetchWhatsNew() async {
        do {
            let res = try await networkingManager.request(session: .shared, .getCodaApiData(documentId: .AppDoc,
                                                                                            tableId: .marketingTableId),
                                                          type: ShowMarketingInApp.self)

            handleResponse(response: res)
        } catch {
            print("whats new error: ", error.localizedDescription)
            self.error = error
        }
    }

    private func handleResponse(response: ShowMarketingInApp) {
        if let marketingRow = response.items.first(where: { $0.id == marketingRowId }) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.showMarketingFromApi = marketingRow.values.showMarketing
                self.whatNewUrl = marketingRow.values.marketingUrl
                self.checkShouldShowMarketingPage()
            }
        }
    }

    private func checkShouldShowMarketingPage() {
        guard showMarketingFromApi, isValidURL(whatNewUrl) else {
            self.shouldShowMarketingPage = false
            return
        }
        self.shouldShowMarketingPage = true
    }

    private func isValidURL(_ urlString: String?) -> Bool {
        guard let urlString = urlString, let _ = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}

// test class
class MarketingVmSuccessTests: XCTestCase {
    private var networkMock: NetworkingManagerImplementation!
    private var marketingVM: MarketingViewModel!

    override func setUp() async throws {
        try await super.setUp()
    }

    override func tearDown() async throws {
        networkMock = nil
        marketingVM = nil

        try await super.tearDown()
    }

    private func createViewModel(with successType: MarketingMockSuccessType) {
        networkMock = MarketingNetworkManagerSuccessMock(successType: successType)
        marketingVM = MarketingViewModel(netwokringManager: networkMock)
    }

    func test_FetchWhatsNew_Success_showMarketing_hasUrl() async {
        createViewModel(with: .showMarketing_hasUrl)

        await marketingVM.fetchWhatsNew()

        XCTAssertTrue(marketingVM.shouldShowMarketingPage, "show marketing page should be true")
        XCTAssertEqual(marketingVM.whatNewUrl, "https://myurl.com", "Urls dont match")
    }

I put a break point on my first assertion and I put a break point on my final function in VM(isValidURL) and my assertion fires first.

Replace DispatchQueue.main.async with MainActor.run

Idk the solution, but the issue is that the change in state you're testing for happens on the main thread (with DispatchQueue.main.async {}). Your tests are not waiting for this async main thread code to complete.

@JoakimDanielson thank you, This would be accepted answer as its working. Once switching over to MainActor.Run things started working

You can replace ObservableObject with .task when you use async funcs

A few observations:

If you were to use GCD, you would add completion handler closures parameters to both handleResponse and fetchWhatsNew, and your asynchronous work would call that closure when the data is retrieved. In the absence of that, GCD will start the work item, but the caller has no way of knowing when it is done and the properties have been updated.
But, we should avoid introducing GCD in a Swift concurrency codebase. We should remain within structured concurrency.

Therefore, the handleResponse function should be async and fetchWhatsNew should await the results, so that it does not return until the properties have been updated. That eliminates the risk of the test reaching the test of the properties before they have been set.

Because this is a view model, the properties should be published on the main actor. At the very least, the properties should be isolated to the main actor.
Or, even easier, isolate the whole view model to the main actor. Apple explicitly recommends that ObservableObject types be isolated to the main actor in WWDC 2021 videos Swift concurrency: Update a sample app and Discover concurrency in SwiftUI.
This ensures that the published properties, shouldShowMarketingPage and whatNewUrl are published on the main thread. (It also ensures that the exposed error property safely can be accessed from the view.) And it completely eliminates the need for the GCD dispatch to the main queue. (Generally, one should avoid invoking GCD from Swift concurrency codebases.)


Thus, perhaps something like:
@MainActor                                                            // note, main actor
final class MarketingViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published private(set) var shouldShowMarketingPage: Bool = false
    @Published private(set) var whatNewUrl: String?

    /// bool value from the api response
    private var showMarketingFromApi = false
    private(set) var error: Error?

    …

    func fetchWhatsNew() async {
        do {
            let res = try await networkingManager.request(…)

            await handleResponse(response: res)                       // note `await`
        } catch {
            print("whats new error: ", error.localizedDescription)
            self.error = error
        }
    }

    private func handleResponse(response: ShowMarketingInApp) async { // note, `async`
        guard let marketingRow = response.items.first(where: { $0.id == marketingRowId }) else {
            return
        }

        showMarketingFromApi = marketingRow.values.showMarketing
        whatNewUrl = marketingRow.values.marketingUrl
        checkShouldShowMarketingPage()
    }

    …
}


Thanks for the response. I did some testing with @MainActor and I don't like that on a class as everything in the class runs on the main thread.
So what I have implemented that is working comes from  @Joakim Danielson in the comments above but using
await MainActor.run {} when I update the published vars. But yes making that handleResponse function async solved this.

If you don’t want to isolate the whole type to the main actor, at least isolate the properties that will be published and/or accessed from the main thread. You want to enjoy compile-time validation of your code,
